# To implement Dijkstra’s shortest path algorithm on unweighted graphs so that it runs in linear time, which data structure should be used?

Tags: algorithm, graph, stack, queue, dijkstra

To implement Dijkstra’s shortest path algorithm on **unweighted** graphs so that it runs in linear time, the data structure to be used is:

1. Queue
2. Stack
3. Heap
4. B-Tree

I found below answers:

1. A Queue because we can find single source shortest path in unweighted graph by using Breadth first search (BFS) algorithm which using "Queue" data structure , which time O(m+n) (i.e. linear with respect to the number of vertices and edges. )
2. A min heap is required to implement it in linear time because if we delete here  a node in min heap it will not take any time in adjustment because all r having same weight so deletion will take O(1) for one node .. so for n-1 node it will be O(n).

Can someone explain which one is the correct answer?

Comment: You first answer is not even related to Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: @RasulKerimov for unweighted graphs, Dijkstra's algorithm reduces to BFS, so (1) is essentially correct.  (2) is just wrong.

Comment: I don't get it. How Dijkstra can reduce to BFS. Two different approaches.

Comment: @MattTimmermans so option (A) is correct and rest all are false?

Comment: @RasulKerimov every new node discovered will have its initial priority set >= all the priority of all previously discovered nodes, and it will never need to be adjusted.  Nodes can therefore be processed in FIFO order using a queue of discovered nodes, which turns it into BFS

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the graph is unweighted, Dijkstra's algorithm is not needed. A simple BFS will work perfectly in O(E + V) time complexity, i.e. a linear time complexity.

A simple implementation of the algorithm needs a queue data structure.